# After BLE Disconnect, 2nd time Connection never established

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here the the following scenarios:

1. Take fresh connection, Take gett server (BLE Device) which is not paired to any of the client.
2. Try for connect, While connection request is send to the BLE device, Pairing request will be received,Give passkey and bond the device.
3. Communication is running smoothly problem starts when I disconnect from ble device, but still bonding with the device, Disconnection request received to the BLE device, But after one time disconnection, I am not able to connect back to the BLE device,
4. Connect request never received to the BLE device.

I performed this testing on Nexus 6.0, Moto G 3rd gen 6.0.1, Samsung Galaxy 6.0.1, Not able to understand the issue, On some phones Its working smoothly like nexus x 6p, Samsung s4, iOS devices etc.

Comment: Can you sniff what happens during the failed connection attempt ? When you say that the connection request is never received by your BLE device, how can you be sure it's the device that doesn't receive it and not that it just doesn't answer ? And how do you connect to your device ? With a custom app ? Try to reproduce this scenario with a generic BLE app such as nRF Connect on Android or LightBlue on iOS.

Comment: I did this same, I tried with nRF also but same result.